# How to get a unified result on multiple results of a A/B test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

I have a A/B test. this test will generate a P_value every day based on the daily data. For example, I had 5 days' significate and 5 days' non-significate. So if I want a unified result from these 10 values, what should I do, I need some theory-based method as I had to explain this to my boss, I can't just make up one...

Constraint by the computing resource, I had no way of aggregating those 10 days' data to get one p_value.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE** I got an answer from another site which seems reasonable, please comment on this（Sorry I translated this）:

Since the data can not be aggregated, so assuming the data population is huge, you could use Central limit theorem.

Known the `p` value, you could get the `z` value with:

[image]

where `n` is the sample size which is already known;

`σ` is the `std_dev` of a single sample, which is unknown.

For `d` is the total days, and there are `d z_values`

for a single day, you have: [image]

for `d` days data, you have:
[image]

So: [image]

Comment: What you call A/B- testing seems to be usually used to compare the parameters of binomial distributions. In this case you only need the counts of A and B  cases to compute the binomial test, not the entire actual data set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the distributions of the A-group and the B-group are identical, the tests are independent and you are testing on the 5%-level, call the number of positives you obtain $X$. Thus

$X$ ~ $Binom(10, 0.05)$. Which yields a probability of obtaining four or less significant results of:

```
 pbinom(4,10,.05)
[1] 0.9999363
```

In other words it is highly unlikely to obtain 5 false positives from 10 attempts if A and B are drawn from the same distribution.

Comment: Can you elaborate under what conditions would each day be considered an independent draw?

Comment: Dimitriy, why would I do that? Based on @cinqS ' question it is obvious that he and his boss consider the different days as sampling from the same populations of A and B respectively. If the draws were dependent or from different populations the question in this form would make no sense or require additional information. If you think the latter may be the case, address your question to cinqS directly.

Comment: I have a hard time thinking of 10 days as 10 independent trials unless each day's units were completely or at least largely non-overlapping. The use of the binomial hinges on that independence.

Comment: Sure it does! However if they have such an issue they are either not aware of this or they are removing returning visitors when they want to test on the following days. Otherwise @cinqS wouln't think of lumping all days together and complain that he lacks the computational power to do this. I still think that this question is for cinqS and not for me.